# Effect of a driver in the host OS to a Docker process

Tags: docker

I'm new to the Docker world, and I understand that docker is not a VM (but some sort of a user space isolation).

I was wondering what will happen if I install a driver on the host OS. Let's say I have a driver that hooks into the syscall for open (it's not what I'm doing, just an example I made up for this question) and writes "open" every time it is called.

Will I see the open syscalls for the processes inside Docker? Will they look the same as a process call outside of Docker?